# What's the difference between 0(%eax) and (%eax)?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, att

If there is an address of a char array in eax, what's the difference between 0(%eax) and (%eax)?Or are they the same, both refer to the first element in the array?

Comment: when you assembled then disassembled them did you see a difference?

Comment: Think about what `0(%eax)` means. It means that there is an offset of 0 from the value in `eax`. Now, what does `(%eax)` mean? It means the value in `eax`. So as long as `x == x + 0`, no, there is obviously no difference.

Comment: If you're seeing something like `0(%eax)` in disassembler output (as opposed to assembly source code) then the 0 is probably the target of a relocation that would change it some other value when the object file is linked.

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly the same. You could prove this easily by assembling and then disassembling the two instructions:

```
movl (%eax),%edx
movl 0(%eax),%edx
```

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   67 8b 10                mov    (%eax),%edx
   3:   67 8b 10                mov    (%eax),%edx
```

Notice that they have exactly the same encoding in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same.

Asuming that you had eax set correctly to point to the address of the first element in the array, would could use movb to put a byte of data in the array using it.

Comment: What does `MOVB` have to do with anything here? If it's just a random example, it's particularly confusing because you cannot use `MOVB` with `EAX`, as shown in the question; a BYTE-sized register is required. Perhaps a better example would have been `MOVZBL`? Or just `MOVL` to store a DWORD-sized value.

Comment: The question asked about  char array in eax, so accessing elements of the array would require a movb.  ie: movb $32, 0(%eax)